# I want to connect respberry pi3 with smartphone through respberry hotspot

Tags: pi-3

I am actually making a quadcopter which you can control with your smartphone but i am facing an issue in making connection. I want to give static IP Address to respberry pi and enable hotspot to make connection between mobile and respberry for communication but i dont know how to do this.
Here are some commands which iam trying but this gives me error

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.10.1

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install hostapd

sudo hostapd hostapd.conf
```

After the last command it give me error

**could not open configuration file 'hostapd.conf' for reading. 
Failed to set up interface with hostapd.conf. 
Failed to initialize interfaces.**

Please tell me how i can connect my mobile with respberry pi.

Comment: Try using the full path to hostapd.conf

Comment: Is there any reason you ignored the warning in `/etc/network/interfaces`?
**# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'**
If you really must use static IP do it properly see [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)

Comment: Obviously, It's impossible to troubleshoot the problem without understanding "hostapd" configuration hence add the "hostapd.conf" file to the question.